# Sorting alphabetically and numerically in Google Sheets or in Excel

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have these values:

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC11
ABC4
ABC5
ABC15
ML1
ML2
ML10
ML3
```

I want to sort these values into numeric order. However in Google Sheets if you sort A-Z then you get

```
ABC1
ABC11
ABC15
ABC2
ABC4
ABC5
ML1
ML10
ML2
ML3
```

And not

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC4
ABC5
ABC11
ABC15
ML1
ML2
ML3
ML10
```

Any ideas on how to get it sorted?

I want this sorted as I have a list of 2000 UK postcode sectors (which always start with letters and then numbers) that I want to be sorted alphabetically and then numerically

For example, the real life sorted data would look like

```
AB1
AB7
AB9
AB10
AB11
DT2
DT3
DT4
DT10
DT11
ML1
ML2
ML3
ML10
ML11
```

Comment: Excel is different from Google Sheets.an Excel-formula solution would not help you in Google sheets. So either change the title to not reference Google "sheerts" or remove the wrong tags and add the correct ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- Your values start with any alpha-chars sequence;
- Your values end with any 1+ digits.

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A1:A6,SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A6,"\d+","|$0"),"|")},"Select Col1 Order By Col2, Col3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=QUERY({A1:A10,INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A10, "[A-Za-z]+")),INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A10, "\d+")*1)},"select Col1 order by Col2, Col3")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks just updated the question though as I forgot to mention the list doesn't always start with ABC.

Comment: @goose84 Try my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

just sort it:

```
=SORT(A1:A, REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\D+"), 1, REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A, "\d+")*1, 1)
```

[image]